# ¿Cómo ordenar un array que tiene un string con datos numéricos en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, ordenar, javascript-metodo

Tengo un array de string con datos numéricos, los cuales necesito ordenar de mayor a menor.

Este es mi array:

```js
let x = [
   'FRA 55', 'RUS 28', 'NED 25', 'NZL 25', 'ESP 19', 'INA 2', 'ITA 40', 'NIG 1', 'USA 54', 'JAM 17', 'COL 2', 'KOR 3', 'SWE 23', 'ARM 3'
]
```

como puedo considerar solo los números para ordenar usando el método `sort`

Este es mi código:

```js
const computeData = (datos, medal) =>{
   const arrayOfNoc =[];
   const  deportes= datos.filter(athletes => athletes.medal === medal)

   for (let i= 0; i < deportes.length; i ++){ 
      arrayOfNoc.push(deportes[i].noc) 
      const teamOfSilver = []; 

      for (let j=0; j < arrayOfNoc.length; j++){ 
         const totalSilverTeam = arrayOfNoc[j] + " " + 
         arrayOfNoc.filter(team => team === arrayOfNoc[j]).length  
           
         teamOfSilver.push(totalSilverTeam) 
      }
      const uniqueTeam = new Set (teamOfSilver); 
      let x = Array.from(uniqueTeam); 
   }
   console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Tu **Array** está compuesto por valores de, **Un código ISO de algún país** + **Un número**. ¿Verdad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ayudarte un poco con el uso de [**Regex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) para obtener el valor númerico, y posteriormente ordenar con el método [**sort()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Suponiendo que tus valores, siempre serán un patrón de:

- **N** cantidad de caracteres alfabeticos **+** Un espacio **+** **N** cantidad de caracteres numéricos

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
function orderBy(array){
  
  const output = array.sort( (a, b) => {
    
    // Obtenemos solo los valores numéricos de ambos
    let first = a.match(/([0-9]+)$/g)[0]
    let second = b.match(/([0-9]+)$/g)[0]

    // Encontramos la diferencia de los resultados
    let result = parseInt(first) - parseInt(second)
    result = Math.sign(result)
    
    // Averiguamos si debemos anteponerlo o superponerlo
    return result === -1 ? 
    1 :
    result === 1 ?
    -1 :
    0
    
  })
  
  // Retornamos el resultado
  return output
  
}

const data = [
   'FRA 55', 'RUS 28', 'NED 25', 'NZL 25', 'ESP 19', 'INA 2', 'ITA 40', 'NIG 1', 'USA 54', 'JAM 17', 'COL 2', 'KOR 3', 'SWE 23', 'ARM 3'
]

console.log( orderBy(data) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let x = [
   'FRA 55', 'RUS 28', 'NED 25', 'NZL 25', 'ESP 19', 'INA 2', 'ITA 40', 'NIG 1', 'USA 54', 'JAM 17', 'COL 2', 'KOR 3', 'SWE 23', 'ARM 3'
]

const toN = s => Number(s.match(/\d+/)[0]);

let result = x.sort((f, s) => toN(s) - toN(f));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: ¿Cómo funciona este código? Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero a tu respuesta le falta algo de contexto y explicación, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.